Chrome Update Causes Input Fields to Break in JavaScript Libraries
I couldn’t find a clear solution to this issue, so I’m sharing my problem and the workaround that resolved it for our application.
After the recent Chrome update (currently on version 130.0.6723.70, though other nearby versions may be affected), input fields within certain jQuery/JavaScript libraries—particularly popover and select2—stopped responding within modals in our company's SaaS application. The issue is that input fields embedded in these libraries wouldn’t respond to focus, typing, or even cursor display, whether using a mouse or keyboard.
The fix that worked for us involved specifying the parent or container element during initialization.
For popover, we added a container property to link to a parent container like this:
$(document).popover({
    ...
    container: "#someParent" // Use an element, class, or ID selector here
});

For select2, the dropdownParent property was used to specify a parent, as in this example:
<script>
    $('#mySelect2').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#myModal')
    });
</script>

This approach helped restore functionality across both libraries. If you encounter similar issues with other inputs or JavaScript libraries, try finding an equivalent container/parent property during initialization.
I’m not sure exactly what changed in Chrome to cause this, but this solution should serve as a temporary fix until the browser is updated with a proper solution.
Hope this helps!
